# Array of objects in angular doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I have a problem with two objects.

First object usersHotel

```
usersHotel:[
   {id:0, linked:false,hotel:
     {code:1, namehotel:'r1'}
   },
   {id:1,linked:false,hotel:
      {code:2, namehotel:'n1'}
   },
   {id:2, linked:false,hotel:
     {code:3, namehotel:'a1'}
   }
]
```

Second object hotels

```
hotels:[ 
  {code:1, namehotel:'r1'},
  {code:2, namehotel:'n1'},
  {code:3, namehotel:'z1'},
  {code:4, namehotel:'t1'}
]
```

i want to show this element from

```
hotels :[
   {code:3, namehotel:'z1'},
   {code:4, namehotel:'t1'}
]
```

it means not common with the two arrays of object:

this is my code:

```
var hotelsName=[];
$scope.getHotelByUserName = function (id) { 
  UsersService.getHotelByUserName(id).then( function(data){
    $scope.usersHotel=data;
      if( $scope.userHotels != null){
        angular.forEach($scope.userHotels, function(value,index) {
          angular.forEach($scope.hotels  , function(hotel,key){
            if(hotel.code!=value.hotel.code){
              $scope.hotelsName.push(hotel);
            }  
          }); 
        });
      }      
  }).catch( function onFail(errorResponse) { 
      console.error('Error while getting Hotel By User Name');
      console.log(errorResponse);
  });
};
```

i have a problem that the push function for the hotelsName object doesn't take the value, i get an empty object. Really don't understand why? any help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

small thing quickly to rectify

Just update `var hotelsName = []` to     `$scope.hotelsName=[];`

```
$scope.hotelsName=[];
$scope.getHotelByUserName = function (id) { 
  UsersService.getHotelByUserName(id).then( function(data){
    $scope.usersHotel=data;
      if( $scope.userHotels != null){
        angular.forEach($scope.userHotels, function(value,index) {
          angular.forEach($scope.hotels  , function(hotel,key){
            if(hotel.code!=value.hotel.code){
              $scope.hotelsName.push(hotel);
            }  
          }); 
        });
      }      
  }).catch( function onFail(errorResponse) { 
      console.error('Error while getting Hotel By User Name');
      console.log(errorResponse);
  });
};
```

Comment: thanks for your response @Lalit Sachdeva , but it still the same problem the push function doesn't work because the hotelsName is still empty.